# How to prevent entering text containing spaces in mySQL

Tags: mysql, text, space

It happens occasionally that users erroneously enter text with a trailing space in a text column, which is hard to spot visually. This can later cause problems when this text field has to be matched against another where the trailing space is not present. Is it possible in mySQL to enforce that a text string cannot contain a certain character (space in this case)?

Thankful for feedback!

Comment: that's not mysql's job. you should be inserting "clean" data from the get-go, which means do the space removal in your client-side code, BEFORE it ever gets anywhere near mysql.

Comment: my-sql is a rathr random mish-mash of different technologies... So check exact version and engines....  There are two SQL technologies that can help: BEFORE-UPDATE-OR-INSERT TRIGGERs that can transparently fix the data by your rules and CHECK CONSTRAINTs that can block inserting of invalid data. If your database support any of those - u can use it. I could code both in Firebird SQL, but not in MYSQL, so would not make it an answer

Comment: What Marc said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mysql function a simple way is based on trim()

```
select 
  trim('    try with trim  ')
, length (trim('    try with trim  '))
, length ('    try with trim  ') 
from dual ;
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to achieve what you want:

1. Check the user input in your application and reject it if it contains a space. If your primary worry is the quality of the user inputs, then this is probably the best way to do this.
2. You can remove spaces (or just starting / trailing spaces) from the user input either in the application logic or using sql.

If you opt for removing all spaces from the user input in sql, then use the [replace() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace). If you just want to remove the starting and trailing spaces, then use the [trim() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) to achieve the desired results.

Comment: Doing this in the application layer is the best way to do this. Enforcing this on the database level leads to frustration, especially when for some reason you *need* a space there.